# Colocar imagen al fondo de su contenedor

Tags: html, css

estoy intentando colocar una imagen debajo de todo en un box, intente muchos metodos, como un background-url y tambien moviendo sus margenes hasta abajo, pero en cuanto cambio el tamaño de la pagina, este se mueve para cualquier lado, hay alguna forma de dejar la imagen completamente fija en una caja hecha en CSS?

Esto es lo que hice yo ayer, pero me cuesta desplazar la imagen ya que al cambiar el tamaño de la caja, la imagen se mueve a cualquier lado

```
 <section>
    <div class="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
             Qui nam vitae perspiciatis dolorum iusto quidem,
              totam veniam obcaecati iure rem 
            officia itaque possimus quo voluptatibus asperiores,
             fuga reiciendis unde vero?</p>

             <img  src="img/header-bottom.png" alt="" srcset="">
    </div>
</section>
```

codigo CSS:

```
    .content{
    width: 80%;
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    height: 750px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top:50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.content img{
    
    position: relative;
    max-width: 500px;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Esa es mi pregunta
Gracias por su ayuda
Saludos

Comment: Puedes publicar tu código? Ya que asi es más fácil ayudarte.

Comment: Tal y como dicen, agrega tu codigo html y css para poder replicar el problema y ayudarte a buscar la solución

Comment: Ya lo edite y agregue las cosas, creo que antes tenia un codigo mucho mas prolijo, pero en la desesperacion pude haber hecho cualquier cosa

Comment: Si, quiero que quede ahi, pero cuando la muevo modificando su margen-top, al cambiar el tamaño del box se mueve hacia cualquier lado

Comment: prabaste darle un position relative al contenedor y a la img postion absolute  y bottom 0 ?

Comment: Si @facuaquino, en vez de bajar, sube, no se porque

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

- Al contenedor con la clase `content` dale un display de tipo `flex`
- Para mover ahora la imagen debajo del texto, usamos `flex-direction` con un valor de `column`
- Para separar la imagen del texto y moverla al fondo hacemos uso de `justify-content: space-between;`
- Para mover a los elementos al centro (*ahora horizontalmente por el cambio hecho en el punto 2*) hacemos uso de `align-items: center;`
- Para lograr que la imagen no tenga un espacio de separación con el borde inferior del contenedor hacemos uso de `margin: 0;`

Entonces tu CSS debe quedar así:

```
  * {
    margin: 0;
  }
.content{
  width: 80%;
  background-color: yellowgreen;
  height: 750px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Y se vería mas o menos así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resto de tu HTML queda igual.....

Comment: Millones de gracias!